# Show that $\cos(2\pi nx) \nrightarrow 0$ almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on trying to show that the sequence $\{\cos(2\pi n x)\}$ does **not** converge to $0$ almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$.

I have already shown that $\{\cos(2\pi n x)\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $L^2([0,1])$ equipped with Lebesgue measure and hence converges to $0$ weakly in $L^2$.

I also have shown that $\int_0^1 \cos^2(2\pi nx) = \frac{1}{2}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Trying to utilize the above fact, I came up with something which is probably wrong:

By way of contradiction, suppose it is  true. Then, $ \space f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for all $x \in E \subset [0,1] $ such that $E^c$ has measure $0$. Then there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\cos(2\pi nx)| < \frac{1}{2}$ whenever $n \geq N$ and $x \in E$. This implies that $\cos^2(2\pi nx) < \frac{1}{4}$ for $n \geq N$. But then, by properties of the Lebesgue integral, we must have:
$$\int_E \cos^2(2\pi nx) = \int_0^1 \cos^2(2\pi nx) < \frac{1}{4}m(E) = \frac{1}{4} $$
which is a contradiction.

If anyone could tell me where my proof goes wrong and point me in the direction of a correct solution, I would be highly appreciative.

Comment: You are assuming that this $N$ is uniform: this is not true, this $N$ is in fact depending on $x$. More precisely, you say that for all $x\in E$ it is $f_n(x)\to 0$. That means that for EACH $x\in E$ there exists a $N_x\in\mathbb{N}$ (i added $_x$ to point out dependence) such that for all $n\geq N_x$ it is $|f_n(x)|<1/2$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Right, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not quite right, since the number $N$ that you choose may depend on $x\in E$.

One thinkable solution is to use that $f_n(x):=|\cos(2\pi n x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and hence, if $f_n$ did converge to $0$ almost everywhere, dominated convergence would yield the contradiction $\frac12=\int_0^1f_n^2(x)dx \to 0$.

I am not quite sure that this is the question, though. Maybe you actually want to show the stronger statement that for almost every $x\in[0,1]$ the term $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $0$ (which is also true).

Comment: So we would apply DCT to the sequence $f_n^2$ actually?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that typo. :-) It has been corrected now.

Comment: You say that youre not sure that this is the question, but why not? Does proof by contradiction not work here?

Comment: My proof shows that the statement "$f_n$ converges to 0 a.e." is wrong. In other words: for any measurable set $E\subset[0,1]$ with $\lambda(E^c)=0$ there are $x\in E$ such that $f_n(x)$ does not converge to 0.

A similar, but stronger (and more interesting) statement is the following: There is a measurable set $E\subset[0,1]$ with $\lambda(E^c)=0$ such that for all $x\in E$ the term $f_n(x)$ does not converge to 0. Note the different position of "there is" and "for all".

Maybe the actual question on your mind was the second one. The opening sentence of your post is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you @Mars Plastic. Very helpful responses.

Comment: You're welcome. :-)